# Spinner Drop arrow image is not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-spinner

I am working on a project where I have to show the spinner. Spinner is working properly but no drop image is showing.. Can you guys please help me out to figer this issue.

This is my xml

```
  <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/seasonSpinner"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/forgot_logo_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/preorderbtn_height"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ppv_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/seasonSpinner_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ppv_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ppv_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_theme"
                android:overlapAnchor="false"
                android:paddingRight="0dip"
                android:popupBackground="#e2e1e1"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:theme="@style/applicationTheme"/>
```

This is my drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerColor="@color/spinnerbackground"
            android:endColor="@color/spinnerbackground"
            android:startColor="@color/spinnerbackground"
            android:type="linear" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/lollipop_spiner_color2" />

        <corners android:radius="1dp" />

        <padding
            android:left="0dp"
            android:right="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:width="@dimen/listview_img_width"
    android:height="@dimen/listview_img_height"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_arrow"
    android:gravity="right|center"
    android:right="10dp" />


</layer-list>
```

and in style.xml

```
<style name="applicationTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/mySpinnerStyle</item>
</style>
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: because you set `android:background`of spinner.

Comment: you have to use .9 patch file for spinner background